# try to get user information by populate() but return empty array with no errors

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I try to make one method for signup to two types of user ' buyer and seller ' .
When I save  seller , I should get all information about their ' storeinfo ' , see my updated code below .
I used populate() but I get an empty array .
Is my idea wrong ?

**code for signup**

```
exports.signupUser = async (req, res, next) => {  
    role = req.body.role
    const user = new User(req.body)
    const seller = new Seller(req.body)
    try{
        if(role=='seller'){
            await seller.save()
            await user.save()
            const token = await user.generateToken()
            res.status(200).send({
                error: null,
                apiStatus:true,
                data: {user,seller ,token}
            })
        }
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateToken()
        res.status(200).send({
            error: null,
            apiStatus:true,
            data: {user, token}
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).send({
            error: error.message,
            apiStatus:false,
            data: 'unauthorized user'
        })

    }
}
```

**code for login**

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findUserByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateToken()
        console.log(user.role)
        if(user.role=='seller'){
            console.log(user._id)
           await User.findOne({_id: user._id}).populate('storeinfo').exec(function(err, user) {
            if (err) {console.log(err)}
            res.status(200).send({
                error: null,
                apiStatus:true,
                user,token
            })})
        }
        res.status(200).send({
            error: null,
            apiStatus:true,
            data: {user, token}
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).send({
            error: error.message,
            apiStatus:false,
            data: 'Something went wrong'
        })
       
    }
}
```

**schema user**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({

    first_name: { type: String,required:true},
    last_name: { type: String,required:true},
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, trim: true,lowercase: true ,validate(value) {
      if (!validator.isEmail(value)) throw new Error("Invalid Email");  },
    },
    password: { type: String,minlength: 6,required: true, trim: true, match: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/},
    role: { type: String, enum: ['admin','seller', 'user'], default: 'user' ,required: true},
    mobileNumber: { type: String,default:'',trim: true,
      validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isMobilePhone(value, ["ar-EG"]))
          throw new Error("invalid phone number");
      },
    }, 
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    storeinfo:{    
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref:'Seller',
    },
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
userSchema.methods.generateToken = async function(){
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toString() , role:user.role}, process.env.JWTKEY)
    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({token})
    await user.save()
    return token
}
// login
userSchema.statics.findUserByCredentials =  async(email, password)=>{
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    if(!user) throw new Error('invalid email')
    const matched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if(!matched) throw new Error('invalid password')
    return user
}
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
 module.exports = User
```

**seller schema**

```
const SellerSchema =  new Schema(
  {
    storeName: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true
     },
    image: {
      type: String,
     // required: true,
    }, 
    addresses:[
               {
                  street: String,
                  locality: String,
                  aptName: String,
                  lat: Number,
                  lng: Number,
                 
                }
          ],
       
    numberOfBranches: Number,
    _userId:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Item" }]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
const Seller = mongoose.model('Seller', SellerSchema)

module.exports = Seller
```

Comment: You need to assign Seller's `_id` to `user.storeinfo` before saving the user. Otherwise the populate method has nothing to find the seller by.

Comment: @molda  Thanks a lot!  it works